# Polynomial regression seems to give different coefficients depending on Python or R

Tags: r, regression, python, polynomial

When I fit a polynomial on the `Boston` data set with R, I seem to get different results than when I use Python. Example code with R:

```
library(MASS)
attach(Boston)
lm.fit = lm(nox ~ poly(dis, 3), data = Boston)
summary(lm.fit)
```

This yields the coefficients

```
Coefficients:
               Estimate
(Intercept)    0.554695
poly(dis, 3)1 -2.003096
poly(dis, 3)2  0.856330
poly(dis, 3)3 -0.318049
```

With Python:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.api as sm
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

boston = datasets.load_boston()
df = pd.DataFrame(boston['data'], columns=boston['feature_names'])
df = pd.concat([df, pd.Series(boston['target'], name='MEDV')], axis=1)
df_x = df[['DIS']]
df_y = df[['NOX']]

poly = PolynomialFeatures(3)
df_x_transform = poly.fit_transform(df_x)

lin_regressor = LinearRegression()
lin_regressor.fit(df_x_transform, df_y) 
print(lin_regressor.intercept_, lin_regressor.coef_)
```

Yields:

```
0.9341280720211879 [ 0.         -0.18208169  0.02192766 -0.000885  ]
```

And with `statsmodels`:

```
model = sm.OLS(df_y, df_x_transform)
fitted = model.fit()
print(fitted.summary())
```

We get the same result as with `sklearn`:

```
                 coef
const          0.9341
x1            -0.1821
x2             0.0219
x3            -0.0009
```

How is this possible?

Comment: R uses an orthogonal basis expansion while PolynomialFeautres does not. Try passing `raw=TRUE` in `poly`. What are the results?

Comment: Using an orthogonal basis results in more stable matrix inversion, if I recall correctly.  I think if you just google around, you can find the basis that R uses.  I can't remember off the top of my head.

Comment: @DemetriPananos thank you, I will google around! If you write your first comment as an asnwer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R uses an orthogonal basis expansion while PolynomialFeautres does not.  Try passing `raw=TRUE` in `poly`.  What are the results?